# PowerShell script for importing psts

Tags: powershell, import, exchange-server, pst

I need a help with this script.

```
$data = Import-CSV C:\temp\import.csv
ForEach ($i in $data){
$pstpath = "\\server\pst$\" + $i.folder + "\"
$user = $i.user
$folder = $i.folder
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path $pstpath -Filter *.pst | New-MailboxImportRequest -FilePath "$pstpath + $_.name" - Mailbox $user -Name "Import $user $_.name" -BadItemLimit 30 -ConflictResolutionOption KeepAll -TargetRootFolder $_.name -IsArchive -confirm: $false

}
```

I've got this error for each pst in folder:

The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline in
put or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (archive.pst:PSObject) [New-MailboxImportRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,New-MailboxImportRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `New-MailboxImportRequest` cmdlet doesn't accept pipeline input, and if it did you's have to remove the '-FilePath "$pstpath + $_.name"' part from the command.

Try this instead:

```
$data = Import-CSV C:\temp\import.csv
ForEach ($i in $data){

    $user = $i.user
    $folder = $i.folder
    $pstpath = "\\server\pst$\$folder"

    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path $pstpath -Filter *.pst | Foreach-Object{
        New-MailboxImportRequest -FilePath $_.FullName - Mailbox $user -Name "Import $user $($_.Name)" -BadItemLimit 30 -ConflictResolutionOption KeepAll -TargetRootFolder $_.Name -IsArchive -Confirm:$false
    }

}
```

Comment: it's working :) Ia have another question. -TargetRootFolder is now $_.Name and the name of folder is Archive.pst. How can I remove .pst in the name? Is It possible?